# Android fragment activity not receiving ACTION_SCREEN_OFF or ACTION_SCREEN_ON even

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-broadcastreceiver

I think I may be missing some little detail and will feel very stupid once this is solved but....

I have many activities that all extend a base class. In the base class there is a Broadcast receiver to catch ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON.

This will log out the user and return to the main screen.

```
public class ScreenBReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
    public void autoLogout(Context context)
        {
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        ma.setLoggedIn(false);
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        FDFragmentActivity.this.finish();
        context.startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
            {
            this.autoLogout(context);
            }
        }
    }
public ScreenBReceiver screenLogout;
```

However, there is one (1) activity that is not receiving the action.
I cannot for the life of me figure out why the one activity is not receiving this action.

I don't know what else to post. If more info is needed please say so.
All of the activities in the manifest are declared identical.

Neither the xml layout nor the activity code specify that the screen be kept on.

What else could there be?

EDIT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    pi = new PollInterface(mContext);
    screenLogout = new ScreenBReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    registerReceiver(screenLogout, filter);
    registerReceiver(screenLogout, filter2);
    .......

@Override
public void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();
    try
        {
        unregisterReceiver(screenLogout);
        }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iae)
        {
        // Android can't just let it pass that a receiver was already unregistered.
        // So, just ignore the daft exception it throws when unregistering twice.
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you registering and un-registering the receiver ? can you post code for the base class.

Comment: Oh, it may be useful to know that while on this activity the screen stays on permanently. It will not turn off like the rest of the screens based on the Android display setting.

Comment: Are there any 'hidden' or weird xml layout attributes that could force the screen to stay on?  I am using eclipse with adt.

Comment: you should register in onResume and unregister in onStop. You cannot rely on "onDestroy"